# Can I convert Android App to iOS App?

Tags: android, objective-c

I heard that j2objc exists. Can I convert my Android App to iOS App with this or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. From the [j2objc project page](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/):

> The goal is to write an app's non-UI code (such as data access, or application logic) in Java

Answer (score 1):

Did you read their explanation of what j2objc [is and is not](http://code.google.com/p/j2objc/)? It allows you to integrate java into ObjectiveC apps, but it's specifically NOT an independent/cross-platform UI toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You have to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Try look this http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/